# How to exclude the digit number in the android reg expression

Tags: android, regex, android-edittext

I am working to validate the name field, since there are so many country using different symbol as first, last name, I am going to validate the field by checking whether there is a number among the characters

```
private static final String NAME_REGEX = "\\d*";

public static boolean isName(EditText editText) {
        return isValid(editText, NAME_REGEX) ? false : true; //Match digit pattern return true , meaning it is not a valid name
    }

public static boolean isValid(EditText editText, String regex) {
    String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    return Pattern.matches(regex, text) ? true : false;
}
```

However, this pattern seems not working as I add some number it is still valid , what is the correct way of implement this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Obligatory: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: you should use InputFilter

Comment: Thanks for your info. I wonder any one use the number (and is it prohibit?) as their name?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Thanks for reply. Can I valid if the user copy the text?

Comment: @user782104: There was one case in Sweden, but the name was disapprove by court.

Comment: yep it will work for even copy text. just try and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use regx. InputFilter is proper way to do this kind of validation.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText edit;

    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (source.length() > 0) {
                if (Character.isDigit(source.charAt(0)))
                    return "";
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes , i use both android:singleLine="true" and input filter since I also need to prevent the user insert new line, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just do this

```
private static final String NAME_REGEX = ".*\\d.";
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the EditText to inputType to "textPersonName"   there is no need for validation.

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```